# Allowing user to change column order of the datagrid view

Tags: c#

I am using Win forms and  have a databound DataGridView which has around 31 columns.

AllowUserToOrderColumn is set to true. But since the number of column is 31 its quite difficult for the user to move columns from one end to another.

so I want to create a form which will display all the columns of the datagridview and with the click of up down button allow them to change the order.
I have named my textBox(readonly) from textbox0 to textbox30.

Is there any way to display the column order in text boxes.

Like when we click EditColumns in the designer view.

Comment: `textbox0 to textbox30` would be 31 columns, i don't understand what you want to achieve in the new form with all those `TextBox` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta i want to display the Header text of the column in these textboxses

Comment: @V4Vendetta sorry I edited my question i have 31 columns and i want to display the column name in these text boxes

Answer (score 1):

Certainly:

Look at the DisplayIndex of the columns -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkfe535h.aspx

With this, you should be able to read them and change them by code.